# Override FluentNHibernate Auto mapping

Tags: fluent, automapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I need change for the next class data type assumed by default FluentNHibernate Automapping

```
public class plaparte
{
public virtual int id { get; private set; }
public virtual int vivos { get; set; }
public virtual int lesionados { get; set; }
public virtual int quemados { get; set; }
public virtual int muertos { get; set; }
public virtual int otros { get; set; }
public virtual string colaboracion { get; set; }
public virtual decimal hectareas { get; set; }
public virtual string reconocimiento { get; set; }
public virtual string disposiciones { get; set; }
public virtual plaserv plaserv { get; set; }
}
}
```

I need for this class only the string type to be converted into TEXT in database
If I change by

```
public virtual string[] reconocimiento { get; set; }
```

FluentNHibernate takes a BLOB data type

I can do something like?

```
public class plaparteMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<plaparte>
{
public void Override(AutoMapping<plaparte> mapping)
{
  Map(x => x.disposiciones).CustomSqlTypeIs("TEXT");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem I am using:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
...
public class plaparte
{
...
[StringLength(4000)]
public virtual string disposiciones { get; set; }
```

To create TEXT fields

[Update]

For work I need to create the next class

```
class StringLengthConvention : AttributePropertyConvention<StringLengthAttribute>
{
    protected override void Apply(StringLengthAttribute attribute, IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Length(attribute.MaximumLength);
    }
}
```

is also necessary to add the convention Fluent automap
Like

```
    static AutoPersistenceModel CreateAutomappings()
    {
        return AutoMap.AssemblyOf<plaparte>(new mapAutomapConfiguration())
            .Conventions.Setup(c =>
            {
                c.Add<StringLengthConvention>();
            });
    }
```